# How does Zomato autocomplete their textbox for address?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2, zomato-api

In the android version of their app, if we type some letters, it will try to suggest places' names that starts with those letters. Is that from their server or do they use google places' API? Can anyone teach me whether to get the autocomplete from their server or combining google places' API & Zomato's API

I am trying to make an app using Zomato's API but the documentation for their API is so limited...

Thank you for the help! Sorry for bad English

Answer (score 0):

You can use Locations API to search for a location – city, neighborhood or geo-coordinates(as desired) to implement the autocomplete feature.

Here's the documentation:
https://developers.zomato.com/documentation#!/location/locations

Answer (score 0):

Well, it uses [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete#add_an_autocomplete_widget) for this autocomplete. The autocomplete service in the Google Places API for Android returns places predictions in response to user search queries. As the user types, the autocomplete service returns suggestions for places.

You can add autocomplete to your app in the following ways:

- Add an autocomplete widget to save development time and ensure a consistent user experience.
- Get place predictions programmatically to create a customized user experience.

Here are some tutorials that can show you on how to make autocomplete with your application.

- [Google Place API Autocomplete Service in Android Application](http://codetheory.in/google-place-api-autocomplete-service-in-android-application/)
- [Android Google Places Autocomplete API Example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-places-autocomplete-api-example/)

Comment: Does it really use Google Places API? Because I think the addresses that Zomato has are different from the ones from Google Places. Google Places has a lot more compared to Zomato (as far as I know)

Comment: But, it is better to use the places api because it is the official api for the autocomplete if you want to use Google API

Comment: Actually, what I'm afraid of if I used Google Places API is if when I used an address from the Places' autocomplete, and then that place does not exist in Zomato API's places...

Comment: I'm not familiar omato API, but what is the reason you want to use this instead of Places API? is there any specific reason?

Comment: They offer more information about the restaurants compared to Places API.